# Batch Script to copy files from set locations

Tags: batch-file, search, copy, criteria

I am trying to get this bat file to copy file based on certain criteria.

What am I missing to get this to work?

```bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "PATTERN=*.nwd"
set "SOURCE=C:\NWD\"
set "TARGET=C:\NWM\"
set "STRING1=191058"

pushd "%SOURCE%" && (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /S /M /I /R /C:"\<%STRING1%\>" "%PATTERN%"') do (
            ECHO copy "%%F" "%TARGET%"\"%%~nxE"
        )
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code you can do this:

```bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "PATTERN=*.nwd"
set "SOURCE=C:\NWD\"
set "TARGET=C:\NWM\"
set "STRING1=191058"

pushd "%SOURCE%" && (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /S /M /I /R /C:"\<%STRING1%\>" "%PATTERN%"') do (
        ECHO copy "%%F" "%TARGET%%%~nxF"
    )
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

I'd change it to this though:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "PATTERN=*.nwd"
Set "SOURCE=C:\NWD"
Set "TARGET=C:\NWM"
Set "STRING1=191058"

CD /D "%SOURCE%" 2>Nul || Exit /B

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /SM "\<%STRING1%\>" "%PATTERN%"') Do (
    Echo Copy /Y "%%A" "%TARGET%\%%~nxA")
```

*You may wish to add a pause in order to see the `Echo` before the script closes*